# Removed item using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.RemoveItem

Tags: c#, csproj

I want to remove file programatically using `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.RemoveItem` for that I have written following lines of code.

```
var projectFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/test.csproj");

var strIncludeFiles = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(projectFileName);
var item1 = Helper.GetProjectItem(strIncludeFiles, "\"Compile\"=\"Areas\\TEST\\Models\\Doc1Doc3XRefScriptingModel.cs");
strIncludeFiles.RemoveItem(item1);
strIncludeFiles.Save();
public static ProjectItem GetProjectItem(this Project project, string filePath)
{
    var includePath = filePath.Substring(project.DirectoryPath.Length + 1);
    var projectItem = project.GetItems("Compile").FirstOrDefault(item => item.EvaluatedInclude.Equals(filePath));
    return projectItem;
}
```

But in `item1` I always get `null` value.So please help me where I'm wrong and how to remove the file.

Answer (score 0):

item1 is null not related to Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.RemoveItem. This is an issue in your FirstOrDefault in the method, GetProjectItem. If you iterate through the items in the project you will see the format of EvaluatedInclude. There is no "Compile"= prefixing the property, EvaluatedInclude. Just specify a folder path to match EvaluatedInclude.

```
var item1 = Helper.GetProjectItem(strIncludeFiles, 
    "Areas\\TEST\\Models\\Doc1Doc3XRefScriptingModel.cs");
```